# Troubles using Android GraphView Library

Tags: android, graph

ive read the introductory information on using the (android) GraphView library and can not manage to get it to work, when using the demo application (everything was rebuilt, it worked), but now implementing its methods in my activity will not.

The documentation and demo code can be seen at [GraphView](http://android-graphview.org/#download)

here is my main activity:

```
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
//create the column headers 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graph_view);
    // init example series data
    GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
          new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
          , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
          , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
          , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
    });

    GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
          this // context
          , "GraphViewDemo" // heading
    );
    graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
    layout.addView(graphView);
}
```

and here is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="250dip"
   android:id="@+id/graph1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use GraphView library? IMAO there is a better library to create graphs like aChartEngine, which is probably the most popular graph library for Android with good documentation. You can find documentation and Demo application [here](http://www.achartengine.org/)

Comment: I just checked out the code provided from aChartEngine and the documentation and community provided the information needed to get this up and running. Thanks,